# which technologies are used by Faceapp?

Tags: android, google-play

I am eagerly want to know how many types of technologies are used in "faceapp" application.which is working with selfies of users.it provides change gender,change age of user through its selfies and give result as per user filter..then how they do it ?? 
Help and give spark to my curiosity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me

While they showing processing your image  in app that image  are being uploading on faceApp server. 
After upload image on server. faceApp created a AI/ML. which process your image and give back image with filter selected by you

all filters are applied on server end by AI(Artificial Intelligence )/ML(Machine Learning )